# Formatting a parsable float literal

Tags: c++, formatting

I need to output float numbers using printf formatting, in such a way that the generated string are valid float literals. As the numbers are arbitrary, I use the `%g` format descriptor, followed by an `f`.

This raises a problem in one specific case: if the mantissa in an integer and no exponent is appended. In this case, the number is printed without the decimal point nor exponent, resulting in an illegal constant.

E.g.

```
3.3                 3.3f        ok
3000000000000000.   3e+015f     ok
0.000000000000003   3e-015f     ok
3                   3f          nok
```

Do you see an easy way to handle this corner case ?

Comment: sooooooo `%#g`? But is this to be later compiled or should be human readable? If you want human readable, then use `%g`. If you want to use by computer later, don't use `%g`, you're gonna loose precision, use just `%a`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: bingo !

Comment: @KamilCuk: must be compiler readable in fact, but also human friendly. I know about possible loss of accuracy, but in my context this is harmless.

Comment: @KamilCuk: with %#g, trailing zeroes are appended to integers. In an ideal world, I would prefer not.

Comment: `trailing zeroes are appended to integer` write it to a string and remove the zeros yourself.

Comment: @KamilCuk: yes, of course, I can edit "manually", but this is a little tricky because of the possible exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the mantissa in an integer and no exponent is appended. In this case, the number is printed without the decimal point nor exponent

So use the alternative form with `%#g`. It will always print a decimal separator, but it will also disable removing trailing zeros from the output.